Information coefficient as loss function of XGBoost
I am trying to train an XGBoost regressor for stock price prediction. I want to customize the objective function to be Information Coefficient (IC). The definition of IC is the Pearson correlation coefficient between y_pred and y_true, i.e.,
$$ IC =
\frac{\frac{1}{n}\hat{y}^Ty-\mathrm{E}\left[ \hat{y} \right] \mathrm{E}\left[ y \right]}{\sigma \left[ \hat{y} \right] \sigma \left[ y \right]}
$$
XGBoost requires a gradient and a Hessian of the loss function. I have sorted out that the first derivative of IC w.r.t. $\hat{y}$ is
$$
\frac{\partial IC}{\partial \hat{y}}=\frac{\left( \hat{y}-\mathrm{E}\hat{y} \right) \sigma \left[ y \right]}{n\sigma \left[ \hat{y} \right]},
$$
which is a vector. Now I am confused about the Hessian part, as it will be a vectors derivative over a vector. How do I do that? Is Hessian a vector, a scalar, or a matrix here? It would be really helpful if someone could illustrate the process of calculating Hessian in this case.
